# Is this a valid mongo command format? db.[database].[collection].find()

Tags: mongodb

I use MongoHub for most of my queries.
I noticed that it generates a mongo command when I fill out the search criteria.

For example, it will generate something like this:

```
db.myDatabase.myCollection.find().sort({ "_id": 1}).skip(0).limit(30)
```

When I type `db.myDatabase.myCollection.find()` into the mongo shell command, nothing is returned. (No error message is generated either).

If instead I type:

```
{
use myDatabase
db.myCollection.find()
}
```

then I get results back.

Anyone know how mongo interprets `db.[???].[????].find()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db.[???].[????].find()
```

Actually creates a sub collection using the notation, example:

```
> db.gt.gf.insert({g:1})
> show collections
gt.gf
system.indexes
```

So even though it is valid it might not be what your looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is

```
use <dbname>;
db.<collname>.find()
```

I've not used MongoHub, but if it's a log you're looking at maybe it puts the database name in the string / log for reference?

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/

Comment: When I enter db.<???>.<collname>.find() into the mongo shell, it doesn't complain though. So this tells me that it's a valid format, but I'm not sure what format that is. Do you know?